# Class 'My_Form_Login' not found (Zend Framework)... why?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I know there are other StackOverflow questions that overlap with my question, but I have not found the answer within them, so I'm going to give some specifics here and hopefully someone can help.

In my ZF 1.11.10 project I define class My_Form_Login() in

```
/application/forms/Login.php
```

My application.ini has:

```
appnamespace = My
```

I get a Class not found fatal error from PHP when trying to create a new My_Form_Login() from one of my controllers.

Now, as I understand it, I shouldn't need the following in my Bootstrap because it's already a default resource type:

```
$oResourceLoader->addResourceType('forms', "forms/", 'Form');
```

or even

```
$oResourceLoader->addResourceType('forms', "forms/", 'My_Form');
```

But even if I do add this, I get the fatal error.  Help please!

Comment: Could you provide the error message and some code from your controller/form, otherwise all we can do is wild guessing? For instance: If you are working on a GNU/Linux or Mac-system the filesystem is case-sensitive; are you sure your path & class name match. Meaning your file `/application/forms/Login.php` is really called `My_Form_Login` and not `My_form_Login` or something like that.

Comment: Sorry @mahok - I wasn't sure how much detail to add from the outset.  I had of course checked case, spelling etc. but you weren't to know that from my question... I'll bear that in mind in future!  As you can see, I've posted an answer to the problem... took me quite a while to find!  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem just yesterday, I am a newbie when it comes to Zend so I am not sure my anwser is correct.

For me however I fixed this in my index.php file by initialising the autloader which I had not before;

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Answer (score 1):

Put your form class in the library folder (or anywhere in the include path) of the project (keep the My_Form_Login class name)

```
/application/...
/library/My/Form/Login.php
...
/public
```

in application.ini put

```
[production]
...
autoloaderNamespaces.my = "My_"
...
```

Comment: Thanks - but that's a workaround rather than fixing the problem.  Having rebuilt the project from scratch and compared application.ini, I've now found the issue.  Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the error was occurring because of these missing entries from my application.ini:

```
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
```

These lines fix the problem even if my Bootstrap is empty: presumably by including the above, it means that the Boostraps parent constructor is run and that appears to be necessary to kick the resource loaders into action.